# How to aggregate plots into figure with subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've read the answers related to this already and have followed this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(221)   #top left
fig.add_subplot(222)   #top right
fig.add_subplot(223)   #bottom left
fig.add_subplot(224)   #bottom right 
plt.show()
```

Which is great, now I have a figure with four empty subplots.

What I can't figure out is how to set the `#top left` subplot to show my plot `x` where x is a `matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot` that I've already generated.

My code in total is:

```
plt1 = plot.scatter(foo,bar)
plt2 = plot.line(bar, baz)
plt3 = plot.scatter(you, get)
plt4 = plot.line(the, picture)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(221)   #top left
fig.add_subplot(222)   #top right
fig.add_subplot(223)   #bottom left
fig.add_subplot(224)   #bottom right 

# Here is where I got lost
# I want figure subplot 221 to show plt1 etc...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep track the Axes objects returned by `add_subplot`.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)   #top left
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)   #top right
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)   #bottom left
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224)   #bottom right
```

And then you can do:

```
ax1.plot(...)
ax2.boxplot(...)
ax3.hist(...)
# etc
```

But I would just do this:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
```

and go from there.

Comment: I guess what's hanging me up is that `ax1.plot(...)` strips out a lot of the formatting I've been able to achieve with `df[['col1','col2']].plot()`, namely displaying the index of datestamps as the x-axis rather than index n, and axis titles etc...


The plot I like is generated by `statusPlt = df[['a','b','c']].plot(title='Status of stuff by Create Date')`
which shows me a nice line chart, grouped by column value over the date index


Replacing it with `ax1.plot(df[['a','b','c']])` shows the x axis as index value

Comment: so you should do `df[['col1','col2']].plot(ax=ax1)`

Comment: @TylerWood and set the formatting on the axes directly (e.g., `ax.set_xlabel(...)`)

Comment: Ahhh, this `ax` variable is what was escaping me. the fig has different `ax` created as `ax1...axn` through the `fig.add_subplot` statements and then I can use those to tell which plots to put where.

Comment: @TylerWood exactly -- the only time you should use the `plt` module is to explicitly create axes and figure object. after thatm you should operate on those objects directly (or specify them in e.g., pandas plotting methods).

Answer (score 1):

Is it principal to draw before creating subplots? If no, try this code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(221)   #top left
plt1 = plt.scatter(foo,bar)
fig.add_subplot(222)   #top right
plt2 = plt.line(bar, baz)
fig.add_subplot(223)   #bottom left
plt3 = plt.scatter(you, get)
fig.add_subplot(224)   #bottom right 
plt4 = plt.line(the, picture)
```

Comment: Only because I already have the code for the plots set up how I want them to appear.

Going this route will require again setting axes labels, titles, legends, axes scales etc...